# Query for returning if more than 3 related rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want a report of all SalesPersons with more than 3 sales.

So the result should just be a list of SalesPersonId's.

```
Table Sales:
-buyerId
-amount
-salespersonId
```

So if a SalespersonId has 3+ sales, you will find 3 rows for this SalePersonId in the table.

Comment: This is not a question, post a question, the related code...

Comment: This is a great place to start: http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not hard, I think you could do it yourself if you knew what the group by and having statements do.

```
SELECT SALESPERSONID
FROM SALES
GROUP BY SALESPERSONID
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

As a side note, these rows are not related.  In a relational database "related" means something specific and this is not that.

Comment: This will return all salespersons with not only >3, but also =3, other than that, great solution.

Comment: @MazBros -- Interesting... the last line says 3+ and 3 rows (implying 3 or more) and the first line says more than 3.  Hard to know what the poster wanted, I went by the last line when I wrote it.  In any case it is easy to put in or take out the `=`.

Comment: Agreed, it is not clear what the poster really wanted, either way, with a little change any of the desired results would be achived